# What's the difference between the cost of ASP.NET and PHP hosting?

Tags: php, asp.net, hosting, web-hosting

Several times I heard that PHP hosting is much cheaper than ASP.NET one. I decided to check it out and went to Google. But there are different categories of hosting (it can be expensive or not). There is a cheap ASP.NET hosting and expensive PHP hosting, and vice versa.
So I can't know exactly if there is a difference between their price.
So, is there a big difference between the cost of ASP.NET and PHP hosting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the cost of asp.net hosting is higher due to microsoft licencing fees vs linux's lack of fees. It's usually 5-10 dollars a month more depending on what you're getting. You do get what you pay for, so be wary when looking at bargain hosts. Any hosting that only costs a few dollars a month (under $10) isn't going to provide the same level of service or support that one that costs more will.

I've had good experience for linux hosting with Bluehost. Dreamhost is another, they are more flexible but I have had performance issues.

For windows hosting, I know the rackspace cloud sites does both linux and windows environments rather well. I've had issues with them in the past (provisioning) but they seem to have cleaned up a lot in the past year.

Good luck finding someplace to host your code!

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be *much* difference in terms of the server software unless you have additional features: databases, any sort of back-end software such as analytics, or some sort of plugins.  That being said, .Net hosting can be *slightly* more expensive, as it is not open source.  Ultimately, any Windows hosting would be a bit more expensive because you can run a LAMP server for next to nothing.

In my eyes, the main price points are: amount of server space, bandwidth per month, domains, access, etc.